# Get Single View From FrameLayout

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-framelayout

I have FrameLayout in which i added many views pragmatically first type of views are ImageViews and Second one are TextViews.

```
 // adding TextView
 textview.setText(text);
 textview.setTypeFace(typeface);
 framelayout.addView(textview);

// adding ImageView
imageview.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c10));
framelayout.addView(imageview);
```

Now thing that i want to figured out is 
**how to get any single view that clicked by user?**

Comment: share your  full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to set on click listeners with functionality individually to the all views before adding them to the FrameLayout.

However it might be better to predefine a single onClickListener like this:

```
View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        };
```

and set the same one to all the views. Within the onClick, there are 2 ways to detect which view was clicked:

1) If you are sure that there will be only one image and one text view, you can use the following within onClick(View v)

```
    if (v instanceof ImageView){     

    }else if(v instanceof TextView){

    }
```

2) Or you can set ids to the views and then use this :

```
     switch (v.getId()) {

     }
```

Also, dont forget to set ids to every view because the id is what we will run switch case over.

Note: Above API 17 you can use view.generateViewId() to get the id and save it

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You must set a click listener to the view first, so android will dispatch the click event to your app.

something like

```
    textview.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //response user click action
        }
    });
```

when user clicked the `textview`, this `onClick(View v)` will be called.